# Node.js "callback not defined" when trying to to a http request

Tags: node.js, http, callback

totally new to Node.js and this callback thing is driving me nuts.

I am writing a Skill for an Amazon Echo. As part of this I am trying to send an SMS using BulkSMS.com via a HTTP Request. The http.request has a callback which parses the response. (To take the BulkSMS API out of the equation in the example below I am just trying to get it working using a http request to Random.org (i.e. www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new)

However I am getting an error saying that the callback is not defined.

*{
    "errorMessage": "callback is not defined",
    "errorType": "ReferenceError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Emergency.eventHandlers.onLaunch (/var/task/index.js:54:11)",
        "AlexaSkill.requestHandlers.LaunchRequest (/var/task/AlexaSkill.js:16:37)",
        "AlexaSkill.execute (/var/task/AlexaSkill.js:97:24)",
        "exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:100:15)"
    ]
}*

I am sure I am doing something totally stupid and for that I apologize, but I just can't see it.

Here is the onLaunch event handler in my index.js. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Emergency.prototype.eventHandlers.onLaunch = function (launchRequest, session, response) {
console.log("Emergency onLaunch requestId: " + launchRequest.requestId + ", sessionId: " + session.sessionId);

console.log("Attempting to send SMS");


callback = function(response) {
    var str = '';

    console.log("In callback");
    //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
        console.log("Getting Data");
    });

    //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
    response.on('end', function () {
        console.log("End of response");
        console.log(str);
    });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();



console.log("Finished sending SMS");
var speechOutput = "<speak>SMS sent</speak>";
response.tell(speechOutput);
};
```

Full index.js is below.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * App ID for the skill
 */
var APP_ID = "amzn1.ask.skill.eb8cf94a-848f-45ae-9792-xxxxxxxxxx";

/**
 * The AlexaSkill prototype and helper functions
 */
var AlexaSkill = require('AlexaSkill');
var http = require('http');
var request = require("request");


//var Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');

var SKILL_NAME = 'Emergency';


var Emergency = function () {
    AlexaSkill.call(this, APP_ID);
    console.log("APP_ID set");
};

var alexaResponse = "";


//The url we want is: 'www.random.org/integers/?   num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
 var options = {
     host: 'www.random.org',
     path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
};


// Extend AlexaSkill
Emergency.prototype = Object.create(AlexaSkill.prototype);
Emergency.prototype.constructor = Emergency;



Emergency.prototype.eventHandlers.onSessionStarted = function (sessionStartedRequest, session) {
    console.log("Emergency onSessionStarted requestId: " +     sessionStartedRequest.requestId
    + ", sessionId: " + session.sessionId);
    // any initialization logic goes here
};

Emergency.prototype.eventHandlers.onLaunch = function (launchRequest, session, response) {
    console.log("Emergency onLaunch requestId: " + launchRequest.requestId + ", sessionId: " + session.sessionId);

    console.log("Attempting to send SMS");


    callback = function(response) {
        var str = '';

        console.log("In callback");
        //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
            console.log("Getting Data");
        });

        //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log("End of response");
            console.log(str);
        });
    }

    http.request(options, callback).end();

    console.log("Finished sending SMS");
    var speechOutput = "<speak>SMS sent</speak>";
    response.tell(speechOutput);
};

Emergency.prototype.eventHandlers.onSessionEnded = function (sessionEndedRequest, session) {
    console.log("Emergency onSessionEnded requestId: " +     sessionEndedRequest.requestId
        + ", sessionId: " + session.sessionId);
    // any cleanup logic goes here
};

Emergency.prototype.intentHandlers = {
    // register custom intent handlers

    EmergencyIntent: function (intent, session, response) {
    // Get a random "never" phrase from the list

    }
};


// Create the handler that responds to the Alexa Request.
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
// Create an instance of the Emergency skill.
var emergency = new Emergency();    
emergency.execute(event, context);
};
```

Comment: You code snippet seem to be working fine. Is this the complete code?

Comment: Thanks for having a look Sridhar - here is the complete code.

Answer (score 2):

> However I am getting an error saying that the callback is not defined.

That's because of `'use strict';` mode.

> First, strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global variables. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work" (although future failure is possible: likely, in modern JavaScript). Assignments which would accidentally create global variables instead throw in strict mode:

More on this in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors)

```
accidentalGlobalVariable = 'hello world';
console.log(accidentalGlobalVariable); // logs hello world
```

In strict mode,

```
'use strict';
accidentalGlobalVariable = 'hello world';
console.log(accidentalGlobalVariable); // errors out
```

**Error**

```
accidentalGlobalVariable = 'hello world';
                         ^
ReferenceError: accidentalGlobalVariable is not defined
```

In your code sample, If I run without strict mode it works,

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'www.random.org',
  path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
};

callback = function (response) {
  console.log('response statusCode', response.statusCode);
};

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

but if I run with strict mode,

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'www.random.org',
  path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
};

callback = function (response) {
  console.log('response statusCode', response.statusCode);
};

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

I too get error because strict mode errors out `callback`

```
callback = function (response) {
         ^
ReferenceError: callback is not defined
```

you can remedy it by

Using `var` or `let` in assignment.

```
var callback = function (response) {
  console.log('response statusCode', response.statusCode);
};
```

Eliminating the need of `callback` all together and use an anonymous function instead.

```
http.request(options, function (response) {
  console.log('response statusCode', response.statusCode);
}).end();
```

Comment: Thank you Sridhar, you have saved me from pulling out what little hair I have left.

Comment: Tried your suggestions Sridhar, not getting the "callback not defined" issue anymore but still cannot get the http request to work using either callback or the anonymous function approach.  In either case I get the logs before and after the http request but nothing logged from the anonymous function.

Comment: This code seem to be working fine by logging response code. So, in your case, it isn't logging inside the anonymous function? Strange. Can you update the question with the new code?

Comment: I dealt with the same problem and your answer fixed my issue, thank you